# MYSQL: Combine two different tables and calculate SUM of one column and GROUP BY two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sum

I have a below tables:

TABLE #1:

```
       SELECT * FROM portal.reports;

        # id, date, ont_type, quantity
        '1', '2020-04-05', '2511', '200'
        '2', '2020-04-05', '5120', '350'
        '3', '2020-04-05', '2520', '150'
        '4', '2020-04-05', '5114', '400'
        '5', '2020-04-05', 'HG851', '200'
        '6', '2020-04-05', 'HG851A', '400'
        '7', '2020-04-05', 'MA5620G', '9000'
        '8', '2020-04-05', 'OT550', '7000'
        '9', '2020-04-05', 'OT925', '2000'
        '10', '2020-04-05', 'OT928', '2000'
        '11', '2020-04-06', '2520', '150'
        '12', '2020-04-06', '5114', '400'
        '13', '2020-04-06', 'HG851', '200'
        '14', '2020-04-06', 'HG851A', '400'
```

TABLE #2:

```
        SELECT * FROM portal.ont;

        # ontType, vendor
        '2520', 'APPLE'
        'HG851', 'GOOGLE'
        'HG851A', 'GOOGLE'
        'MA5620G', 'GOOGLE'
        'OT550', 'GOOGLE'
        'OT925', 'GOOGLE'
        '5114', 'APPLE'
        '5120', 'APPLE'
```

INNER JOIN:

```
        SELECT Date(a.date), b.vendor, a.ont_type, a.quantity FROM portal.reports a 
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT vendor, ontType FROM portal.ont  
        ) b ON b.ontType = a.ont_type AND a.date >= '2020-04-05' AND a.date <= '2020-04-08'


        # Date(a.date), vendor, ont_type, quantity
        '2020-04-05', 'APPLE', '2520', '150'
        '2020-04-05', 'GOOGLE', 'HG851', '200'
        '2020-04-05', 'GOOGLE', 'HG851A', '400'
        '2020-04-05', 'GOOGLE', 'MA5620G', '9000'
        '2020-04-05', 'GOOGLE', 'OT550', '7000'
        '2020-04-05', 'GOOGLE', 'OT925', '2000'
        '2020-04-05', 'APPLE', '5114', '400'
        '2020-04-05', 'APPLE', '5120', '350'
        '2020-04-06', 'APPLE', '2520', '150'
        '2020-04-06', 'GOOGLE', 'HG851', '200'
        '2020-04-06', 'GOOGLE', 'HG851A', '400'
        '2020-04-06', 'GOOGLE', '5114', '400'
```

I have to calculate the quantity's total by GROUP BY vendor and date like below:

```
+---------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
|    # date     |  vendor  | ont_type | quantity | total |
+---------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
| '2020-04-05'  | 'APPLE'  | '2520'   | '150'    | '900' |
| '2020-04-05'  | 'APPLE'  | '5114'   | '400'    | '900' |
| '2020-04-05'  | 'APPLE'  | '5120'   | '350'    | '900' |
| '2020-04-06'  | 'APPLE'  | '2520'   | '150'    | '150' |
| '2020-04-06'  | 'GOOGLE' | 'HG851'  | '200'    | '800' |
| '2020-04-06'  | 'GOOGLE' | 'HG851'  | '200'    | '800' |
| '2020-04-06'  | 'GOOGLE' | 'HG851A' | '400'    | '800' |
+---------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
```

how to proceed further?

Comment: What's the problem? Use `SUM(quantity)` and `GROUP BY date, vendor, ont_type`.

Answer (score 1):

You can join and aggregate to get the quantity sold per vendor and day. The total per per vendor can be computed with a window sum (assuming MySQL 8.0):

```
select 
    r.date, 
    o.vendor, 
    o.type, 
    sum(r.quantity) quantity,
    sum(sum(r.quantity)) over(partition by o.vendor) total
from portal.reports r
inner join portal.ont on on o.ont_type = r.ont_type
where r.date between '2020-04-05' and '2020-04-08'
group by r.date, o.vendor, o.type
```

In earlier versions of MySQL, one method to compute the total per vendor is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    r.date, 
    o.vendor, 
    o.type, 
    sum(r.quantity),
    (
        select sum(r1.quantity)
        from portal.reports r1
        inner join portal.ont o1 on o1.ont_type = r1.ont_type
        where o1.vendor = o.vendor and r1.date between '2020-04-05' and '2020-04-08'
    ) total
from portal.reports r
inner join portal.ont on on o.ont_type = r.ont_type
where r.date between '2020-04-05' and '2020-04-08'
group by r.date, o.vendor, o.type
```

Comment: Thank You @GMB for your prompt response. I have used the second query and found a small issue with it. Group BY is not happening for each date separately. It is calculating the quantity's total for all dates.For Eg: 2020-05-04 SUM should be calculated differently and 2020-06-04 SUM should be different. But the result here is... 2020-05-04 + 2020-06-04 + 2020-07-04 total.

Comment: @Cherry: my bad, I forgot to filter on the dates in the subquery. Fixed.

Comment: Sorry to say @GMB... there is no difference in the result.